# Different language on textview in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, unicode

how can i write different language (Bangla) on textview or edittext in Android and for this What version of API i have to need

Answer (score 2):

If you use strings.xml to add a level of indirection for string values, then you can easily localize your strings as in:

```
android:text="@string/main_text_view_hello"
```

So I have a strings.xml in folders:

```
res/values
res/values-en-rCa
res/values-en-rGB
```

Any time I want to change a value for Canada or United Kingdom, I just add it to the appropriate folder. All other values are obtained by default from res/values.

Comment: i have done that but in Bangla(language) it is not supportable they show me some box out there on the emulator...

Comment: Hmmm. I only found this: http://code.google.com/p/bangla-on-android/wiki/BanglaFontInstallation

Comment: @Toukir Naim  I do not know how to do this on an emulator, but you _can_ debug directly over usb from eclipse to an android phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can set text with TextView.setText(String-ID) . String-IDs are managed in strings.xml files which are under res/values folder. If you want another language for example german you need another strings.xml file with the same String-IDs in res/values-de. In android layout files you can reference such string ids with @string/stringid.