# Multiple language text on same activity at same time in android

Tags: android

I need to show a text message in multiple languages on the same activity. Is it possible to do this and if yes, then can some share some reference code or logic to do this.

Comment: search before you ask, lots of example there keyword `Localization`.

Comment: check this issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003287/different-language-on-textview-in-android

Comment: Do you want your text to be compatible with different languages, in which case the link provided by AamirKhan is the place to go, or do you want to have multiple language displayed at the same time ?

Answer (score 2):

use Locale
Create a values-hi folder (for Hindi) along side values folder in res.Inside values-hi create strings.xml. Define string name corresponds to string.xml in values folder.

Java code -

```
hindi_language.setOnClickListner(new OnClickListner(){
public void onclick(View v)
{
Locale locale=new Locale("hi");
Configuration newconfig=new Configuration();
Locale.setDefault(locale);
newconfig.locale=Locale.getDefault();
onConfigurationChanged(newconfig);
//refresh activity
}
});

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
setContentView(yourlayout);
SetTitle(R.string.app_name);
}
```

Comment: it works! But `updateConfiguration` is deprecated. Please update code!

Comment: In `onConfigurationChanged` change code to  Context newContext = createConfigurationContext(newConfig), then setText using newContext. And everything work!

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy.
It has nothing to do with localization.
1. Copy and paste the other language text directly.
Android will display as it is.

```
   <TextView
  android:height="wrap_content"
  android:width="wrap_content"
  android:text="Ladakh ལ་དྭགས" />
```

2. Define it in strings.xml

   ```
   <string name="some_text">Ladakh ལ་དྭགས</string>
   ```